# CGPath clipping

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I want to make something similar to this:

[image: Example]

I tried the following code:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddLines(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, points, sizeof points / sizeof *points);

CGMutablePathRef strokePath = (CGMutablePathRef)CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, data.lineWidth, kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineJoinMiter, 4.f);

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [data.values count]; i++) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(points[i].x - data.dotRadius, points[i].y - data.dotRadius, data.dotRadius * 2, data.dotRadius * 2);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(strokePath, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, rect);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(strokePath, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, CGRectInset(rect, data.lineWidth, data.lineWidth));
}
```

Then to draw this path:

```
CAShapeLayer *layer = self.layers[line];
layer.path = strokePath;
layer.strokeColor = nil;
layer.fillColor = data.lineColor.CGColor;
layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
```

Bt that gives something like:

[image: Result]

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Draw the lines and the circle, not as a compound path, but just as two lines and a circle (and without any fill rule). Then "punch out" the hole at the center of the circle by drawing a smaller filled circle using `kCGBlendModeClear`.

Alternatively, start by clipping out the hole at the center of the circle. Then draw the lines and the circle.

Comment: See my book, starting here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html#_paths_and_drawing The two ways of cutting out the triangular notch at the end of the arrow shaft, in this section and the next section, are exactly what you want to be doing.

Comment: Thanks that should indeed work. I ended up doing it slightly different see below.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up by doing it with a layer mask:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddLines(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, points, sizeof points / sizeof *points);

CGMutablePathRef dotPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < [data.values count]; i++) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(points[i].x - data.dotRadius, points[i].y - data.dotRadius, data.dotRadius * 2, data.dotRadius * 2);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(dotPath, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, rect);
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(dotPath, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, CGRectInset(rect, data.lineWidth, data.lineWidth));
}
CGPathAddPath(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, dotPath);

CGMutablePathRef maskPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(maskPath, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height));
CGPathAddPath(maskPath, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, dotPath);


CAShapeLayer *layer = self.layers[line];
layer.path = strokePath;
layer.lineWidth = 2;
layer.strokeColor = data.lineColor.CGColor;
layer.fillColor = nil;
layer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = maskPath;
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
layer.mask = maskLayer;
```